# jsTree - Change the html icon of nodes

Tags: javascript, html, ember-cli, jstree

I'm using material icons in my project, icons should be in this format:

```
<i class='material-icons'>folder</i>
```

I've used the`types` plugin from jsTree but I was only able to change the image src and the icon css classes.

Thanks in advance.